# Is there a way in python to wrap an url in a name which will not be changed by outlook safelinks, while actual link is transformed

Tags: python-2.7, email, outlook

I've created a python tool which sends links via email.

When the mail is received the link is changed into an Outlook Safelink.

e.g. http://www.google.com will be transformed into https://emea01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%[some_id]%7C1&data=[again_some_code]%3D&reserved=0

I understand why this is done, but it makes reading the mail far less easy.

So my question is: is there some way that I can wrap the www.google.com in my python script in a name, so outlook will use that name to present it in the mail, while the actual URL under that name is transformed in the Safelink?

/*edit*/
What I mean is something like you do it in http:

```
<a href="www.google.com">name</a>
```